# Override OnActivityResult inside Intent is not working - kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, onactivityresult

I'm overriding my OnActivityResult to control some flow in the application.

The problem that it gives an error that it is `overriding nothing`.

here is the code am using :

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
}
```

The error only gone when I add nonnull protection after Intent, to have the code like this :

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
}
```

But that causes a `kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException` error after in the function itself.

Comment: dont forget super.onACtivity...


override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }

Comment: data: Intent? is the correct method signature. So, you must use "data: Intent?". Could you please share more code from your onActivityResult. THen, we can look at the NullPointerException

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Signature of method `onActivityResult` is:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)
```

As you can see, `Intent data` is nullable. So, in order to override the method properly, you must use:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)
```

Since data is nullable, you must use the safe call operator `?` everytime you need to check the intent.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    val action = data?.action
    ...
}
```